# Ubuntu 23.04 - Dell 9310 - AX201 wifi not working

Tags: dell, 23.04

Just upgraded my Dell XPS 13 (9310) laptop to 23.04.  Now the built-in Intel "Wi-Fi 6 AX201" isn't working.  It worked fine with 20.04, 20.10, 21.04, 21.10, 22.04, and 22.10.

Any suggestions?  The wifi adapter is shown with `lshw -c network`.  It appears the `iwlwifi-compat` module crashes on startup.

[image]

Edit: As asked by @chili555

```
$ sudo dkms status
backport-iwlwifi/9904, 5.19.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
backport-iwlwifi/9904, 6.2.0-20-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
xtrx/0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2, 5.19.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
xtrx/0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2, 6.2.0-20-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Performing the reboot after the apt purge now.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo dkms status` If, as I suspect, backport-iwlwifi-dkms is installed, remove it: `sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms` Reboot and let us hear your result.

Comment: @chili555 - I rebooted and the same stacktrace shown in dmesg, trying to reinstall `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` to see if that helps due to the Diff warnings.

Answer (score 1):

With @chili555's identifying of the rabbithole... `sudo apt purge linux-modules-iwlwifi-6.2.0-20-generic` solved it for me.